# Cannot use Scene methods for URL, NSUserActivity, and other External Events without using SwiftUI Lifecycle

Tags: swiftui

I am using the new "pure" SwiftUI `App` and `Scene` structs instead of an `AppDelegate`.

Some of my views accept custom url schemes and user activities using `onOpenURL(perform:)`. Everything works as expected.

However, starting with Beta 6, Xcodes gives the following runtime warning:

> runtime: SwiftUI: Cannot use Scene methods for URL, NSUserActivity, and other External Events without using SwiftUI Lifecycle. Without SwiftUI Lifecycle, advertising and handling External Events wastes resources, and will have unpredictable results.

What exactly am I doing wrong? What is *SwiftUI Lifecycle* referring to?

---

This is what my main `App` struct looks like.
I am attaching some default modifiers to the main view.

```
@main
struct MyApp: App {
    @StateObject var viewModel = GlobalViewModel()
    
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            MainView()
                .applyingDefaultColors()
                .environmentObject(viewModel)
                .environmentObject(TranslationProvider())
                .toggleStyle(SwitchToggleStyle(tint: .accentColor))
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If it has just appeared in Beta6 then submit feedback to Apple - their bug.

Comment: it appears to be with the non-beta xcode 12 and ios 14

Answer (score 0):

SwiftUI Lifecycle refers to views that are rendered as *children* of a Scene, namely the `WindowGroup` struct that is normally returned in the body of the App.

The implication is basically that if you attach "auxiliary" views to the Scene, such as Commands for MacOS, they can't use methods like `.onContinuedUserActivity` and will produce this error. Communicating view state changes in these cases should instead use FocusedValues, where the subscribing view has a `@FocusedBinding` or `@FocusedValue`, and the publishing view injects `.focusedValue(\.someKeyPath, $interestingState)`

Comment: Thanks for the input. Does that also appy to view modifiers inside my `WindowGroup`? I've added my app struct to the question.

Comment: I don't see anything specific to your update that I would think causes this error. What line does it occur on?